# Expression Engine 2.5.5 - New domain overwritten by old domain

Tags: url, redirect, dns, expressionengine

```
domainA = old url,
domainB = new url
```

EE 2.5.5 website ‘domainA’ is being re-branded as ‘domainB.’ Bluehost has both domains on the account; ‘domainB’ is now the primary domain and ‘domainA’ is parked (going to be an Add-on that redirects to ‘domainB’).

Whenever we try to visit ‘domainA’ the browser redirects to ‘domainB’ - it’s the same site, same files, etc. - but the URL needs to reflect the new name. Nothing else is changing.

(Multiple) Bluehost techs have said there must be a redirect in the EE code and/or DB.  I have checked and changed every instance of ‘domainA’ that I could find in:

- CP Home -> Admin -> General Config
- /sitefolder/expressionengine/config/config.php
- The database, particularly exp_sites

Are there any other instances of the original url hidden in the code?

Comment: You've checked .htaccess for anything weird?

Comment: .htaccess, which resides in public_html directory, looks like this:     
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Commonly used to remove index.php from the URL in EE sites

Answer (score 1):

After completely emptying the server and speaking with my fourth (4th!) Bluehost tech today, we discovered that domain forwarding was active on domainB (rerouting it to domainA) in the GoDaddy account (the domains are registered separate from the web host).

Comment: Would have been easier had the client told me about it before hand.